# Why can't a mouseup event prevent a click event

Tags: javascript, dom-events, mouseevent

```js
function h(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  alert(e.type);
  return false;
}

document.querySelector('.wrapper').addEventListener('mouseup', h, false);
document.querySelector('.child').addEventListener('click', h, false);
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <button class='child'>Click me</button>
</div>
```

I expect this to prevent the 'click' event from firing, but it doesn't. However, changing `mouseup` to `mousedown` does in fact prevent the click event.

I've also tried setting the `useCapture` argument to true, and that also doesn't produce the desired behavior with `mouseup`. I've tested this on Chrome and Firefox. Before I file bugs, I figured I'd ask here.

Is this a bug in current browsers, or is it documented behavior?

I've reviewed the [W3C standard (DOM level 2)](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-flow), and I wasn't able to find anything that could explain this behavior, but I could have missed something.

In my particular case, I'm trying to decouple two pieces of code that listen to events on the same element, and I figured using capture events on the part that has priority would  be the most elegant way to solve this, but then I ran into this problem. FWIW, I only have to support officially supported versions of FF and Chrome (includes ESR for FF).

Comment: `preventDefault` and `stopImmediatePropagation` are unnecessary here (by the way), because there's no `<form>` so no submitting with the button, and no multiple events of the same type. And I *think* this is expected behavior because doesn't `mouseup` fire before `click`? So the `.child`'s `mouseup` event fires (and bubbles) before its `click` event (which you have stopped, but it doesn't matter)

Comment: @Ian - I added those in to make sure I didn't get comments like "have you tried x() or y()?". For your other comment, setting `useCapture` to true forces `.wrapper`'s mouseup to happen before the bubble from child. I didn't include this code, because in either case, I should only get one alert() (with a different originating element), right?

Comment: If you want to prevent a mouseclick, use this: http://jsfiddle.net/zhAHt/9/

Comment: @user2645707 - That's not preventing anything. That's just a return before the alert(), which is *not* what I want... to actually use that I'd have to use a global...

Answer (score 1):

[Check out this quirksmode article](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/click.html)

The `click` event:

> Fires when a mousedown and mouseup event occur on the same element.

So when the mouse click is released, both the `mouseup` and `click` events are fired, `click` doesn't wait for the `mouseup` callback to finish. Almost always, `mouseup` and `click` can be used synonymously.

In order to cancel the `click`, like you demonstrated, you can return `false` in the `mousedown` event callback which prevents the `click` event from ever completing.

Comment: That's incorrect, 
return false, o event.preventPropagation will stop the mouseup but no the click event.

Comment: @eveevans I think you are wrong. doing that on the mousedown seems to stop both moseup and click events from being triggered. See my answer... (I tested on chrome)

Comment: Just tried this and it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Finally found a way to prevent click event from firing. Tested on latest Chromium and Firefox. It may be some bug or implementation details.

**Solution**

Handle `onpointerdown` or `onpointerup` event, remove the element and insert it in the same position.

```html
<span>
    <button onpointerdown="let parent = this.parentElement; this.remove(); parent.appendChild(this);" onclick="alert();">TEST</button>
</span>
```

**Result**

```
onpointerdown
onmousedown
onpointerup
onmouseup
<-- no click event occures
```

Comment: Works at least on Chrome, upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to provide my work around for this issue:

```
let click_works = true
this.addEventListener('mousedown', e => {
    click_works = // condition why the click may work or not
})
this.addEventListener('click', e => {
    if (click_works) // Do your stuff
})
```

Hopefully, it will help someone.